# "Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state" Error?

Tags: sql-server, session, state, kill

We use SQL Server 2019 Standard edition on Windows Server 2019. We have 200 users and thousands of connections at the same time.

SQL Server 2019 raises an error

> Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state

Once a week I restart the SQL Server service and the error is gone.

- I install CU1, CU3, CU4, CU5 and CU6... Error doesn't fixed.
- Databases compatibility level: SQL Server 2019 (150)
- Our programs use mostly 4 tables. I read, broken indexes could cause this error. I check these tables indexes, no problem found. Anyway I rebuild all indexes for these 4 tables. Bu error doesn't fixed.

How could I detect the root cause of this error, and how could I fix it?

Comment: Check the SQL Server error log for related messages at the time of the errror.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This site is really for programming questions. I've recommended that this question be moved to our sister site, dba.stackexchange.com, where hopefully a qualified DBA will see your question and provide useful information.

Comment: Thanks. I'll post my question to dba.stackexchange.com.